# Cannot detach screen session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am very new to screen and I have hit C-Something instead of C-a. Now I cannot detach or do any other commands. What can I do to detatch my screen session?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Possibly you got `C-s` (s for "stop") try `C-q` to resume...

Answer (score 54):

If all else fails, login from another terminal and type: `screen -raAdx`. This will reattach your screen as shared and allow you to detach it.

Comment: This is super handy if screen -ls shows your screen as attached, but you dont have a terminal for it

Comment: In case anyone has two attached screen sessions, [possibly] one within the other, I had to use `screen -d -R <screen id>` to get the outer one to detach, otherwise the inner session was the only detaching.

Comment: Black magic! This actually worked. I was having the weird problem Ascherer described, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

ctrl-a+d detaches

Alternative to detatch if you don't need the information on the screen you can simply kill the process.

Not sure of any command that renders the screen unresponsive.

Comment: ^D (C-D) does not terminate the screen!  It may possibly log out of your shell session, which closes the shell session, and thus your screen session, but that won't be the case if you are running more than one window, a foreground application, and other things.

Comment: (Reminder to myself and possibly others who made the same modifications: For me it was shift-ctrl-a and shift-ctrl-d. Probably something I changed myself unwittingly when I switched ctrl-c and ctrl-shift c.)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem today. I was transferring a 100GB file over a 1MBps link, and it was halfway into the transfer when my workstation crashed. I brought PuTTY back up and got on my terminal server, but no combination of the detach / reattach commands would work. I decided i would kill screen, so i checked ps to get the PID. While i was looking at the PS output, i noticed that the BASH session i had used to launch Screen was still running. On a whim, i decided to kill that session instead of screen, thinking "This should be like closing the PuTTY window, which allows me to re-attach." Sure enough, i was able to run "screen -dr" succesffully.

Answer (score 1):

You can also merely logout, by killing the terminal session, then login again and reattach the `screen` session.